# Ionic Force App Update crashes when calling the function to update the App

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, auto-update

I have an **Ionic 3 App** that needs to use **Force Update** to all users of the **App**. I used this package called [Ionic App Update](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-update/). I created an **small express server** that will just serve the **client** for an updates.

Here is my code in my **update.xml** in the **server** or **backend**

```
<update>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <url>http://192.168.214.27:3346/public/android-debug.apk</url>
</update>
```

and in my **server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use('/public', express.static('public'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    shell.exec('./update.sh')
})
app.listen(3336, () => {})
```

The server is working fine there is **no errors**

But when I try to call the **function** of the A**pp Update plugin** the device crashes every time.

Here is my code in my **app.component.ts**

```
constructor() {
this.update()
}

update() {
    console.log('Update check')
    const updateUrl = 'http://192.168.214.27:3346/public/update.xml';
    this.appUpdate.checkAppUpdate(updateUrl).then(() => { console.log('Update available') }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      console.log('No update')
    });
  }
```

I am calling the **update** function every time the app component constructor is initialize.

But when I call the **function** the **app crashes**

Is this more of an **android version** issue or what?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `<version>0.0.2</version>` seems to be the problem. This isn't the format for android version numbers. As per cordova's documentation it is

> Expressed in major/minor/patch notation.

For example version 30.20.48 would be written as 302048.

Read More: 
config.xml - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/
Android Platform Guide - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-the-version-code

Comment: So the format of my version would be like 000001? and when it becomse 0.0.2 it will become 000002?